# Memory leak using Highcharts + AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory-leaks, highcharts

I am using highcharts inside my AngularJS app, combined with `highcharts-ng` directive, and there is a memory leak which I cannot remove. My app consists of a slideshow, where there are slides that swap after a certain amount of time. These slides, include charts.

For making some tests, I have built 3 different snippets:

1 - A simple javascript app that rebuilds a chart every second. This does not produce a memory leak: http://jsfiddle.net/78af7zcm/

2 - An AngularJS app that manages an array of charts. Every second it removes one chart and includes another one, simulating a slideshow behaviour. I couldn't detect a memory leak here: http://plnkr.co/edit/7Zkheiz82ajVusB2EtqH?p=preview

3 - An AngularJS app, similar to number 2, but managing an active chart, which is being modified by listening to an event. The event is listened because in my original app I must do it like this, and here is where the memory leak appears. http://plnkr.co/edit/7cvDrMlWlgLOBAwoNgkW?p=preview . After 1 hour of execution and taking snapshots, I could see this:

[image: After 1 hour of execution and taking snapshots, I could see this:]

Could someone tell me why is this happening?

Comment: I advice you to post this as possibly bug in the tracker [here](https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng)

Comment: I have posted it! Thank you! However, I am not sure that is an issue only of highcharts-ng.

Comment: If problem will appear in native Highcharts, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem taking out the `highcharts-ng` directive and just using native Highcharts. Anyway, I could not understand why it was generating a memory leak but I have already posted it in their site.